# Should I update my Laravel 4 application to Laravel 5 or create a new Laravel 5 application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, upgrade

I've got a couple of Laravel 4 applications that I want to upgrade to Laravel 5. Normally I would use the Laravel docs [upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) to achieve an upgrade to the next version.

But earlier today I read a [blog post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5#getting-started) from Matt Stauffer stating the following:

> Taylor has said publicly that he thinks the better process is actually
>   to start from scratch and copy your code in.

So my question is what should I do, should I update my Laravel 4 application to Laravel 5 or create a new Laravel 5 application and copy/port my whole codebase into it?

Comment: Personally, I'd create a new and (as Taylor recommends) copy your code in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation recommends creating a project from scratch:

> The recommended method of upgrading is to create a new Laravel 5.0 install and then to copy your 4.2 site's unique application files into the new application.

from http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

To be honest, from my experience, it is quite difficult to upgrade to 5.0. There are lots of namespace issues if you already have used them throughout your projects so prepare for a lot of work.

**Update**

Even though this is not directly related, if you do plan to upgrade to Laravel 5.0, take note that the `HTML` and `Form` helpers are now gone and moved into a separate package:
http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I missed that part...which guide is more clear the official Laravel docs or Matt Stauffers blog?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a definitive answer – I barely started following the official docs and decided it is not worth my time. At a glance, the blog post you linked to does _seem_ a little bit more comprehensive. Again – don't take my word for it as I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I went through [Matt Stauffer's guide](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5) just last week - took about 2 1/2 days and was relatively straight forward and very complete. One thing to watch out for is the shift in how some things are done - you **will** be rewriting some code. For example, I had to learn how to use middleware to replace a bunch of filters.

Comment: FWIW, my project is approx. 10,000 to 15,000 lines of code. Just so you have a (very rough) idea of how long this might take. And that 2 1/2 days probably translates to around 12-15 hours with plenty of interruptions :-p

Comment: @kryten thanks for sharing your experience and an estimate for how long it's going to take.

Comment: I know I'm late to this response, but: I wrote the official Laravel upgrade guide based on my original blog post, so they both are essentially the same. The big difference: A) my blog post is more narrative, rather than formal. B) the docs have been tweaked and updated since my blog post by Taylor and other members of the community. So.. whichever is more your priority. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set-up a fresh Laravel 5 application.

Try to understand the new folder structure and everything. Check the Laravel 5 docs and play around with the project for a couple of hours.

Then follow [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) documentation. Copy your files one by one. 
Move in the order of Route, Controller, Helpers, packages, Views.